# How common is it for airport officers to steal valuables from luggage?

Tags: luggage, tsa, lax

I've heard that this happens frequently with the TSA in the United States and almost always in checked-in bags. I'll be travelling soon to Los Angeles for a holiday and I don't know whether to be alert or not.

I remember once leaving an expensive laptop in a checked-in bag from NBO to DUB through ADD and if my bags could transit through countries that pay workers very little without anything being stolen, then it should reason that I'm safe if I put one or two electronics in my suitcases that will be checked in from DUB to LAX?

Am I mistaken or not?

Comment: Recently, in the Dominican republic, the security officer confiscated all liquids from my carry-on, even though they were within limits, and he only picked me. I asked the check-in counter guy later and he told me they do it sometimes to steal perfumes and stuff..

Comment: If something is really precious or important to you I would not put it in checked luggage. This is taking a useless risk. My rule of thumb for checked luggage is: "let's suppose I never get it back, would it be anything more than a mere annoyance to me?" If the answer is yes, then something is in your checked luggage that should not be there

Comment: Theft can happen anywhere during your bag's travels.  It is purely the luck of the draw, if you get something stolen.  I put 100K+ miles in flying every year and the last item I had stolen from baggage was a maglight 20 years ago flying from Kathmandu to Bangkok.

Comment: Doubt anyone can beat this stupidity: I once left $9,000 in a jacket pocket inside a checked-in bag on a flight from Las Vegas to London. I'd intended to wear the jacket aboard but forgot to remove it. I realized shortly after take-off what I'd done. Happily it was still there at the other end.

Comment: Yes, it happens, but you really shouldn't worry about it.  If the device is highly valuable, take it as a carry on.  For clarity, theft can occur anywhere, not just TSA.

Comment: @Zozor And, in the case of many valuable items, "Let's suppose I never get it back, or it gets smashed in transit, ..."

Comment: I echo what @Johns-305 said.  Theft can occur anywhere between when you bag leaves your hands and when you get it back.  TSA has the opportunity to see what is in the bag, but they don't have the exclusive opportunity to open it.  I even considered how easy it would be to take the "wrong bag" off the luggage carousel at bag claim.  You would have a low chance of something valuable, but also fairly low chance of being caught.  You also have an easy alibi of "it looks just like mine".  Then disappear into the crowd.

Comment: I’ve seen a TV newsprogram do a story on it, and they had no trouble getting incedents to happen when staffers flew with ipads etc. in checked bags.

Answer (score 37):

> I've heard that this happens frequently with the TSA in the United States

You may have heard wrong. In 2014 the US airport with most TSA complaints filed was JFK in New York with 891 complaints. In the same year the airport handled 53.3 million customers. It's also fair to assume that not all claims are based on a real event (since it's an easy way to make a quick buck) and the TSA accepts roughly 1/3 of all claims.

I don't think this qualifies as "frequent" as the chances of an incident much less than 1 in 100000. It's often covered in the media in a sensationalist way but only since it makes a good story, not because there is a lot of substance to it. I travel between 100k and 200k miles a year and never had a problem.

Of all the travel threats to your valuable electronics, security screening is a minor one.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63701/discussion-on-answer-by-hilmar-how-common-is-it-for-airport-officers-to-steal-va).

Comment: This answer makes the unstated assumption that all thefts are reported. Is this assumption based on any concrete evidence? Otherwise, the numbers in this answer can only be treated as a lower bound, and the real numbers could be much higher.

Comment: On another track, comparing complaints to passengers is comparing apples to oranges, as not all passengers check bags. Unless the number of passengers can be substituted for the number of checked bags processed, the "chances" reported in this answer are utterly meaningless.

Answer (score 13):

It has little to do with the payment level of the country, but with what they get away with.

In the US, the urban knowledge is that laptops, iPads, etc. get nearly always stolen. That might or might not be true, but our company policy is to *never* put such electronics in the luggage, and *never* accept a forced checking of your carry-on at the boarding (we are asked to miss the flight if they try to force us). That implies to me that they see a major risk.

There is little you can do as the transport regulations allow them to walk away without legal consequences (you can't sue them or send police). The airlines just reimburse you 20 $ per pound (the maximum), and everyone has learned to live with it. The employees know that of course, and are well aware that it is basically risk-free for them to steal.

Comment: The $20/pound rule was abolished by the Montréal Convention in 1999. On an international itinerary, the operating airline is now strictly liable up to about $1500 for damage or loss to checked baggage. But you'll never get that unless you actually sue them.

Comment: Aren't you not even allowed to check them now, since they almost universally contain lithium ion batteries?

Comment: "In the US, the urban knowledge is that laptops, iPads, etc. get nearly always stolen." Not in my urban knowledge. I almost always carry my laptop with me too, but for me, and probably your company, it's not that there's a high risk of it getting stolen, damaged, or lost. It's that in the unlikely event something does happen, the cost of the device and lost data makes it worth the hassle of carrying it with me. For your company, the cost of having proprietary data go missing even once is high enough to outweigh a few missed flights.

Comment: Do you have any data to back this "urban knowledge"? I've never _once_ heard that electronics are "nearly always stolen".

Comment: @DavidK *For your company, the cost of having proprietary data go missing even once is high enough to outweigh a few missed flights*. If this is from a **security** standpoint, this is incorrect. The value of the loss should be equal to the value of the hardware + a bit for the cost of getting a backup back. None of the data should be recoverable from the laptop. This of course implies several other security measures (passwords, certificates, encryption, ...) which are there to protect the data. From an **inconvenience** perspective - yes (one needs to order a laptop, image it etc)

Comment: +1 but you might change one word: legend, instead of knowledge, as urban legend seems to be what OP refers to.

Answer (score 0):

I have travelled a lot over the years by a variety of means: trains, planes, busses, boats, etc.  Also, many locations: Europe, North American, and Asia.  I have suffered a few thefts but none were during flights.  The most transport related one was while buying a train ticket in Calcutta (as it was called when I was there).

However, I adopt the policy suggested by Zozor: don't check anything very valuable.  So, maybe I have not had stuff stolen from my baggage because I am lucky, because I have only encountered honest airline staff, or because there was never anything worth stealing.

I don't even bother locking my checked in baggage.  Since there is nothing very valuable there, I would prefer that someone looked without damaging the case rather than slashed or otherwise forced it open.

Edit (I amended that last line since I just fear that my bag could be slashed by a thief, I don't know actual incident of this happening).

Comment: Actually, the US law forces you to use a lock that officers can open, or otherwise they are allowed to break the lock.

Comment: @sawa So, are there special locks that can be opened by officers but not thieves?  Even if there are, my thoughts are that if a thief sees a tough lock then he will probably just slash the bag or break it open in some other way.   So, the consequences may be worse than if he opened it easily.

Comment: @badjohn that’s the idea but the keys are readily available online.

Comment: It's a similar concept to driving a soft-top convertible - leave the doors unlocked & nothing of value inside. It's cheaper to have them open the door, look around and find nothing than slash the top, look around and find nothing.

Comment: @FreeMan As it happens, I drive a soft-top convertible.

Comment: @badjohn I can't imagine an airport baggage handler or security screener slashing a bag open. Even seeing one bag slashed open moving around the airport's system would be hugely suspicious: no check-in agent would allow a badly damaged bag to enter the system, so it would be completely obvious that the bag had either been damaged by the machines or by an employee. Both of those cases would require investigation. In contrast, if somebody opens a bag, steals something and closes the bag again, nobody will suspect anything until the bag's owner collects their bag, maybe thousands of miles away

Comment: @DavidRicherby I don't fear that authorised, honest personnel might slash my bag.  It is the dishonest ones stealing that I was referring to.  On some modes of transport, this is a common technique.  One friend was robbed on a crowded bus.  His backpack was not even locked but the thief chose to slash it open rather than open it in the normal way.  I guess that the thief thought that my friend would be less likely to notice.  The thief was right, my friend did not notice until it was much too late.  He did not notice the change in weight due it being pressed against the wall.

Comment: @badjohn Sure, but no airport/airline employee is authorized to slash your bag and I explained why no dishonest airport/airline employee would slash your bag without authorization. Please note that the question is specific to air travel: it's not asking about buses or anything else.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I can see that it is unlikely that an employee of any sort would slash bags but others who have gained access to them might. For example, I sometimes wonder about the safety of bags at luggage claim.  Anyone can access them.  The motive of the bus thief for slashing (speed and discretion) might apply as well.  Fiddling with the lock may take longer and be more noticeable than a quick cut.  In an unrelated question the other day, I mentioned that I was once shown into the holding area and told to find my bag. I was left unsupervised with everyone's luggage for several minutes.

Comment: @badjohn Somebody who wants to steal a bag from baggage claim (if that's even possible -- baggage claim is typically not accessible to non-passengers in Europe, for example) will just pick the bag up and walk off with it. Slashing it with a knife in a busy, well-policed place would attract far too much attention. Seriously, people slashing bags with knives at airports is a total non-issue.

Comment: @DavidRicherby In Europe, the baggage area is often not accessible to non-passengers but, in the US, it often is.  Less often post 9/11 but I have seen it open since 9/11.

Comment: @badjohn Yes, I was pointing out that it's essentially impossible in some significant, large places. Do you know of any cases of bags being slashed at publicly accessible baggage reclaims? (In the US or anywhere else.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby No, not in airports but elsewhere.  Nonetheless, I think that my primary advice to avoid valuable items in check-in is valid.  Whether the most likely mode of theft is lock picking, slashing, or simply taking the whole bag is less important.  A downside, for the thief, in taking the whole bag is that more than one or two will look very suspicious.  If you steal just one or two then you might just get a load of dirty laundry (e.g. mine at the end of a business trip).

Comment: @DavidRicherby I amended my answer.

Comment: @FreeMan And one day, you find a homeless guy sleeping in your car...